# Java map value comparisons

Tags: java, dictionary

This could be the entirely wrong usage for the datatype, but I'm trying to create a Map-Set of some sort, so before insertion into the map I'm trying to use

```
//Material is custom class
Map<Integer, Material> x = TreeMap();

if(!x.containsValue(new Material))
     x.put(int val, new Material);
```

My expectation of this is that it would compare two objects generated from the same data would return true, but it appears that this is not the case.  Why is that, and is there an existing solution other than iterating through the entire map to find out if any element contains a Material where all fields are the same as the incoming?

Comment: have u overridden equals and hashCode() in your Material class?

Comment: as long as Material has proper equals and hashcode implemented, containsValue does what u need

Comment: Given that `Material` is the name of a *class*, what do you expect `if(!x.containsValue(Material))` to do? Why are you trying to specify an argument type in your `put` call?

Comment: Material is a class, not object. new Material(); would be an object you can add to the map.

Comment: Interesting how the noncontributory comments get the most upvotes lately.  It's just dirty pseudocode, the first two comments actually provided information that was needed.

Comment: @CaptainPrinny Your "dirty pseudocode" is 100% java syntax so maybe next time just add the new keyword or make clear that it's pseudocode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a well defined class Material

```
public class Material extends Comparable<Material> {
    final int a;
    final String b;
    ...

    public Material(int a, String b, ...) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    @Override
    int compareTo(Material other) {
        int cmp = Integer.compare(a, other.a);
        if (cmp == 0) {
            cmp = b.compareTo(other.b);
        }
        ...
        return cmp;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (other == null || !(other instanceof Material)) {
            return false;
        }
        return compareTo((Material) other) == 0;
    }

    @Override int hashCode() {
        return ...;
    }
```

A `Set` suffices:

```
Set<Material> materials = new HashSet<>(); // hashCode+equals
Set<Material> materials = new TreeSet<>(); // compareTo
```

Now I have made the fields of Material `final` so the object is immutable, as changing would play havoc with the sets ordering.

For a mutable quality, like quantity:

```
Map<Material, Integer> stock = new HashMap<>();
Material material = new Material(...);
stock.put(material, 100);
int quantity = stock.getOrDefault(material, 0); // Java 8
int quantity = 0; // Java 7
{
    Integer q = stock.get(material);
    if (q != null) {
        quantity = q;
    }
}
```

Comment: I used the NetBeans auto generator for the hashcode, is there anything else someone reading this would need to know about defining that?

Comment: NetBeans offers nice IDE support. As you probably know _equal_ objects must have equal hash codes, unequal preferably different for optimal HashMaps. For a TreeMap a fast compareTo is worth; test the fields in the right order, booleans last. For immutable objects a hash code may be stored in a field, for instance upon first call to `hashCode()`.